# Unable to Unfollow deleted questions

Tags: discussion, bug

Seems it's a bug that at leat I'm not able to Unfollow a deleted question (maybe it's true for deleted answer too) either from the Unfollow link under the question itself (not exist) or from the "following" tab in profile.

Unfollowing from "following" tab says this error:

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on

Edit:

per reply in comment, [there is same question asked on main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/703623) already, ***and now [has answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352886/703623)***.

Comment: Posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346423/295232) on the main Meta.

Comment: That's not necessary, other U&L users will face the same problem and they might not visit Meta.SE either.

Comment: OK, I will keep this question open as well. thanks again